# Access an array from the end in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer

I recently noticed that in C, there is an important difference between `array` and `&array` for the following declaration:

```
char array[] = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
```

The former is *a pointer to a char* while the latter is *a pointer to an array of 6 chars*. Also it is notable that the writing `a[b]` is a syntactic sugar for `*(a + b)`. Indeed, you could write `2[array]` and it works perfectly according to the standard.

So we could take advantage of this information to write this:

```
char last_element = (&array)[1][-1];
```

`&array` has a size of 6 chars so `(&array)[1])` is a pointer to chars located right after the array. By looking at `[-1]` I am therefore accessing the last element.

With this I could for example swap the entire array :

```
void swap(char *a, char *b) { *a ^= *b; *b ^= *a; *a ^= *b; }

int main() {
    char u[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(u) / 2; i++)
        swap(&u[i], &(&u)[1][-i - 1]);
}
```

Does this method for accessing an array by the end have flaws?

Comment: FWIW, overly "clever" code such as `void swap(char *a, char *b) { *a ^= *b; *b ^= *a; *a ^= *b; }` is almost always less efficient than just doing the obvious with a temporary value.  "Load register 1 from `a`, load register 2 from `b`, play around with bitwise operations (hopefully not directly to memory!), then store the values" is a lot less efficient than "Load register 1 from `a`, load register 2 from `b`, store r2 in `a` and store r1 in `b`".  If the "clever" code isn't optimized by the compiler, it could do a total of 9 loads/stores. Instead of the 6 used worst-case with a temporary.

Comment: Even though intermediate values are OOB it always calculates a valid address, so it should be ok.

Comment: While the shown code doesn't, beware what swap() does when a == b.

Comment: The difference between the two: `array` and `&array`, in the context of the usage you made, is that the first is a **fully qualified** type while the second not. The proposed usage should work on almost all systems but on some specific system, so it could be an UB. About efficiency I agree with @AndrewHenle.

Comment: sizeof char u[] works okay but if you were to allocate an array using alloc family, then it is not trivial to find the size and therefore use this trick. In this one special case where you are allocating it on the stack You could use this construct.

Comment: IMHO, the flaw is that it is not readable, thus less maintainable for your fellow programmer. The cognitive effort to decipher what is going on relies on deep knowledge and assumptions of the C type system. I'd prefer a `sizeof` expression any time.

Comment: "[`array`] is a pointer to a char" is wrong. It's the only, single mistake in the otherwise sound and true first two paragraphs, but here is the nitpick: `array` is indeed the entire array of 6 `char`s. Not a pointer to an array, and not a pointer to an element, but the entire thing. That's why `sizeof(array)` can return the size of the array. However, apart from the `sizeof` and `&` operators, the array will **decay** into a pointer to its first element in all other contexts. That's why it looks like it is a pointer while it is not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C standard does not define the behavior of `(&array)[1]`.

Consider `&array + 1`. This is defined by the C standard, for two reasons:

- When doing pointer arithmetic, the result is defined for results from the first element (with index 0) of an array to one beyond the last element.
- When doing pointer arithmetic, a pointer to a single object behaves like a pointer to an array with one element. In this case, `&array` is a pointer to a single object (that is itself an array, but the pointer arithmetic is for the pointer-to-the-array, not a pointer-to-an-element).

So `&array + 1` is defined pointer arithmetic that points just beyond the end of `array`.

However, by definition of the subscript operator, `(&array)[1]` is `*(&array + 1)`. While the `&array + 1` is defined, applying `*` to it is not. C 2018 6.5.6 8 explicitly tells us, about result of pointer arithmetic, “If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated.”

Because of the way most compilers are designed, the code in the question may move data around as you desire. However, this is not a behavior you should rely on. You can obtain a good pointer to just beyond the last element of the array with `char *End = array + sizeof array / sizeof *array;`. Then you can use `End[-1]` to refer to the last element, `End[-2]` to refer to the penultimate element, and so on.

Comment: 6.5.3.2p3 (`&` operator): "Similarly, if the operand is the result of a `[]` operator, neither the `&` operator nor the unary `*` that is implied by the `[]` is evaluated and the result is as if the `&` operator were removed and the `[]` operator were changed to a `+` operator."

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: to `&(&u)[1][-i - 1])`, specifically the first use of `&`

Comment: @rici `(&u)[1]` is still problematic, even if you remove/replace outer `&` and `[-i - 1]`

Comment: @LanguageLawyer `(&u)[1]` is the result of an (implicit) `*` operator, so it is not evaluated in this context as per the previous sentence in the clause cited.

Comment: @rici not sure I understand. You transform `&(&u)[1][-i - 1]` to `((&u)[1] + (-i - 1))`. Where is `&` applied to the result of `*` here?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: you're right, that was an appeal to the wrong section of the standard.

Comment: In this case, `(&u)[i]` is `*(&u+1)`; `&u+1` is an expression of type "pointer to `char[10]`", so the result of the dereference is an lvalue of type `char[10]`. This expression does not undergo lvalue conversion; rather, it is decayed to "pointer to `char`" as per 6.3.2.1p3. Note that it is the expression which is decayed, not the evaluation of the expression. Since the expression is no longer an lvalue, 6.3.2.1p1 no longer applies. At least, that's my interpretation.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Also, the usual argument that the use of `(&u)[1]` is UB in this context hinges on the prohibition in Appendix J.2: "An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression `a[1][7]` given the declaration int `a[4][5]`) (6.5.6)". But that doesn't apply in this case, because 6.5.6 allows a pointer to the address just following the array. It's for this reason that J.2 uses `a[1][7]` and not `a[1][6]`.

Comment: @rici The result of decay is a pointer to the first element of the array denoted by the lvalue. Determination of the object identity is part value computation for an lvalue, which is part of evaluation of that lvalue (see 5.1.2.3p2). So I don't understand how conversion to pointer prevents/cancels evaluation of the lvalue.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: But "determination of object identity" and "evaluation" are not the same thing. The fact that determination of object identity is part of some evaluation does not imply that every determination of object identity is part of that evaluation. Since decay changes the *expression* to a non-lvalue, the lvalue cannot have been evaluated. IMHO. (IOW it's not "conversion" to a pointer. Conversion is something that happens to values. Decay is something that happens to expressions.)

Comment: Actually, I now regret adding that parenthesized comment. The standard uses the word "convert" for this case, too. But I stand by its sentiment: converting an expression and converting a value are not the same thing.

Comment: @rici I find your determination of when an expression is (not) evaluated pretentious/intricate. Is lvalue conversion means the expression which undergoes it also not evaluated?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: lvalue conversion is the way lvalues are evaluated, IMHO. In order to do the lvalue conversion, the object identity needs to be determined.

Comment: @rici why array-to-pointer conversion is not the way how array lvalues are evaluated? Your definitions looks arbitrary. Expression is evaluated unless the standard explicitly says it is not, like in `&*E`/`&E1[E2]` case, or logical operators short-circuiting or conditional expression branches evaluation etc.

Comment: @languagelawyer: But you can only evaluate an expression. If the expression is converted to a non-lvalue, then you have a different expression to evaluate and lvalue evaluation doesn't apply.

Comment: @rici _"In order to do the lvalue conversion, the object identity needs to be determined"_ In case of array-to-pointer conversion too. You can't produce a pointer to the first element of you-don't-know-what.

Comment: @languagelawyer: that's true, but as I said before the fact that "determination of object identity" is part of some evaluation doesn't imply that every case of "determination of object identity" is part of that particular evaluation. In the case of conversion to a non-lvalue, 6.5.6 applies for the evaluation, and that explicitly allows one-past-the-end.

Comment: @rici lvalue conversion needs object identity, determination of it is evaluation of lvalue. array-to-pointer conversion needs object identity, but determination of it isn't lvalue evaluation. Is this your point?

Comment: Determination of object identity is *part of* lvalue evaluation. Array-to-pointer conversion doesn't actually need to identify an object. It just needs to compute an address. So maybe I misspoke when I said that it was part of array-to-pointer conversion. My fundamental point is that array-to-pointer conversion is something to happens to expressions, not to values. Once the new expression is created by converting the original expression, it can then be evaluated, and it is evaluated according to the rules for pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: It would be really helpful if the Standard would define terms for the run-time construct that identifies the object referred to by an lvalue (I'd suggest lref), and for the act of processing an lvalue so as to produce an lref (I'd suggest "resolve").  If the Committee were willing to accept that some of the things clang and gcc do should not be considered desirable, adding such terms to the lexicon would make it much easier to define good rules for optimization [e.g. say that operations on an object are generally unsequenced with regard to anything that happens between...

Comment: ...the time an lvalue is resolved and the last operation on a pointer based upon the resulting lref, but then identify constructs that would imply sequencing, such as operations on lrefs that are freshly derived from the same object or references to elements of the same array.

Comment: @rici _"It just needs to compute an address"_ I find this statement meaningless from the Standard POV. I could say something similar about lvalue conversion. Like «it just needs object value, not identity». To get a pointer to the first array element, you need to determine **which** array. Which means determine its identity.

Comment: @languagelawyer: Perhaps, I could go either way on that. But it's not evaluating the lvalue. You can determine the identity of an object without that being part of the evaluation of an lvalue. (Although I personally don't think it's necessary to identify the object in order to do pointer arithmetic.) In any case, I don't think I'm going to convince you, and I'm not in a position to speak with authority since I'm not on the C committee. So I doubt there is any point continuing what is already an excessively long comment chain.

Answer (score 1):

Although the Standard specifies that arrayLvalue[i] means `(*((arrayLvalue)+(i)))`, which would be processed by taking the address of the first element of `arrayLvalue`, gcc sometimes treats `[]`, when applied to an array-type value or lvalue, as an operator which behaves line an indexed version of `.member` syntax, yielding a value or lvalue which the compiler will treat as being part of the array type.  I don't know if this is ever observable when the array-type operand isn't a member of a struct or union, but the effects are clearly demonstrable in cases where it is, and I know of nothing that would guarantee that similar logic wouldn't be applied to nested arrays.

```
struct foo {unsigned char x[12]};
int test1(struct foo *p1, struct foo *p2)
{
    p1->x[0] = 1;
    p2->x[1] = 2;
    return p1->x[0];
}
int test2(struct foo *p1, struct foo *p2)
{
    char *p;
    p1->x[0] = 1;
    (&p2->x[0])[1] = 2;
    return p1->x[0];
}
```

The code gcc generates for `test1` will always return 1, while the generated code for `test2` will return whatever is in p1->x[0].  I am unaware of anything in the Standard or the documentation for gcc that would suggest the two functions should behave differently, nor how one should force a compiler to generate code that would accommodate the case where `p1` and `p2` happen to identify overlapping parts of an allocated block in the event that should be necessary.  Although the optimization used in `test1()` would be reasonable for the function as written, I know of no documented interpretation of the Standard that would treat that case as UB but define the behavior of the code if it wrote to `p2->x[0]` instead of `p2->x[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a for loop where I set i = length of the vector - 1 and each time instead of increasing it, I decrease it until it is greater than 0.
     `for(int i = vet.length;i>0;i--)`